# UICommand components are placed inside an UIData component, ensure that exactly the same DataModel

Tags: jsf, phaselistener

I have an application that falls into the category described by the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-is-not-being-invoked) provided by BalusC.  Specifically number 4.  I tried moving the DataModel object from a request scope bean to a session scoped bean as someone suggested and that resolve the issue.  However since the UI is shared by different sub applications within the application making the DataModel object session scoped causes a whole different set of problems.  Is there a way to restore the DataModel object through a PhaseListener so the "button click" will actually be invoked.  Does anyone have sample code or point me to sample code?

Answer (score 0):

To the point, you just need to ensure that you prepare the same list/datamodel during bean's construction. If this is dependent on some request parameters, then you have to add them as hidden input values of the form as well, so that you can get them from the request parameter map inside the constructor.